# Appilcation stops responding, main thread doing so much work..?

Tags: android, crash

I have created an application in which on click of a button say [next] . I'm calling a method the work of this method is to generate 5 random number and set them on to 5 buttons randomly, on click of each of button it will randomly choose a small (2 sec) audio file and play it. if i'm clicking the button [next] for more than 8 times my whole application is restarting.

If call `nextChangeAdd();` method again and again my application stops respond after more the 10 time function call. please provide me some alternate ? logcat is also  not showing any error

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Addition extends Activity{

    TextView addNo1, addNo2;
    Button option1, option2, option3, option4, next;
    Random randomGenerator;
    Integer randomInt1, randomInt2;
    int flag = 0, setans;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.additionactivity);
        addNo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addNOOne);
        addNo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addNOTwo);
        option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addoption1);
        option2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addoption2);
        option3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addoption3);
        option4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addoption4);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNextBtn);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nextChangeAdd();
            }
        });
        randomGenerator = new Random();
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/StefanieDots.ttf");
        addNo1.setTypeface(tf);
        nextChangeAdd();

    }

    public void nextChangeAdd() {
        randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        setans = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
        if (setans == 0) {
            setans++;
        }
        int ans = randomInt1 + randomInt2;
        String addans = Integer.toString(ans);
        addNo1.setText(randomInt1.toString());
        addNo2.setText(randomInt2.toString());
        List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            while (true) {
                Integer next = randomGenerator.nextInt(19) + 1;
                if (!generated.contains(ans)) {
                    generated.add(next);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        switch (setans) {
        case 1:
            flag = 1;
            option1.setText(addans);
            option1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //rightAns();
                }
            });

            break;
        case 2:
            flag = 2;
            option2.setText(addans);
            option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //rightAns();
                }
            });

            break;
        case 3:
            flag = 3;
            option3.setText(addans);
            option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //rightAns();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 4:
            flag = 4;
            option4.setText(addans);
            option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //rightAns();
                }
            });
                        break;
        }
        String a2 = generated.get(0).toString();
        String a3 = generated.get(1).toString();
        String a4 = generated.get(2).toString();

        if (flag == 1) {
            option2.setText(a2);
            option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
            option3.setText(a3);
            option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
            option4.setText(a4);
            option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
        }
        if (flag == 2) {
            option1.setText(a2);
            option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
            option3.setText(a3);
            option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
            option4.setText(a4);
            option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
        }
        if (flag == 3) {
            option2.setText(a2);
            option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
            option1.setText(a3);
            option1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
            option4.setText(a4);
            option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
        }

        if (flag == 4) {
            option2.setText(a2);
            option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
            option3.setText(a3);
            option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
            option1.setText(a4);
            option1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //wrongAns();
                }
            });
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the code that would take a long time to execute so AsyncTask is not the answer.

In fact, it is a logical error that makes the following an infinite loop:

```
 while (true) {
     Integer next = randomGenerator.nextInt(19) + 1;
     if (!generated.contains(ans)) {
         generated.add(next);
         break;
     }
 }
```

If it happens, that `ans` is generated and inserted into the list, the loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

[Use AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

An asynchronous task is defined by three generic types called Params, Progress and Result.

**Params**: Params is used to send arguments to an asynchronous task.

**Progress**: Progress is used to send data from the asynchronous task to UI thread ( Main Thread ) while task is progressing.

**Result**: Result is used to send data from the the asynchronous task to UI thread, after its execution.

An asynchronous task is completed in four steps as follows :

**onPreExecute**: A callback method executed on UI thread on starting the task.

**doInBackground**: A callback method executed on non UI thread, invoked after onPreExecute method if exists.

**onProgressUpdate**: A callback method executed on UI thread, invoked by the publishProgress() from doInBackground() method.

**onPostExecute**: A callback method executed on UI thread, invoked after the completion of the task.

Comment: all the code in main thread is tightly coupled how shuold i use async task.?